# extract CSS values from a file and make it a dictionary

Tags: python

so there is a separate file that contains all the CSS values where the **beginning and end** of each value is specified with special signs like `$$$` and the keyword of the value is inside `<>`:

```
$$$ 
    <navbar>  /*this is the key word */

    .navbar {  /*here starts the value of the keyword `navbar` until the closing sign `$$$` */
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    .navbar nav ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      }

$$$ /* here it ends */

$$$ /* another value starts */
    <burger>  /*this is the key word */

    .burger input + label { /*here starts the value of the keyword `navbar` until the closing sign `$$$` */
     position: fixed;
     top: 20px;
     right: 40px;
     height: 20px;
     width: 15px;
     z-index: 5;
    }

$$$ /* here it ends */

and so on
```

with that being said, I want to make this whole thing a dictionary that has the key as the word inside `<>` and the value of the key as the block that comes after the word inside `<>` it until the closing `$$$`

so in python file, the output should be:

```
keyword =   {
  "navbar": '''

.navbar {  
margin: 0 auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.navbar nav ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}''',

  "burger":'''

.burger input + label { 
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
right: 40px;
height: 20px;
width: 15px;
z-index: 5;
}''',

#etc...

}
```

how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue!

```
import re
import json

data = """
$$$ 
    <navbar>

    .navbar {
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    .navbar nav ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      }

$$$

$$$
    <burger>

    .burger input + label {
     position: fixed;
     top: 20px;
     right: 40px;
     height: 20px;
     width: 15px;
     z-index: 5;
    }

$$$
"""

pat = re.compile(r'\$\$\$.*?<(.*?)>(.*?)\$\$\$', re.S)

def main():
    result = {}

    buf = data
    while True:
        m = pat.search(buf)
        if not m:
            break
        result[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)
        buf = buf[m.end():]

    for r in result:
        print r
        print result[r]

main()
```

Output:

```
navbar


    .navbar {
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    .navbar nav ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      }


burger


    .burger input + label {
     position: fixed;
     top: 20px;
     right: 40px;
     height: 20px;
     width: 15px;
     z-index: 5;
    }
```

Comment: oh, it's genius! it works just perfectly. here I have been trying to get the data from a separate file, but it gives an error:
 
File "python.py", line 14, in main

    m = pat.search(buf)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

when i tried to write `data = open('style.css', 'r')` instead of `data = '''...'''`

what should i do?

Comment: oh i just only had to write `f=open('style2.css') data = f.read()` haha:) anyway, thank you very much!